# Как получить список популярных репозиториев GitHub в NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express

Я новичок в Backend поэтому прошу проявить терпения. Нужно получить список популярных репозиториев GitHub и затем сохранить в базе данных. Использую express.

Comment: лошадью ходи век воли не видать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.